# How can I format a date datatype to mmm/yyyy?

Tags: sql, informix

ISQL Perform Screen:

I have a date column (format="mmm-dd-yyyy") used for storing "Date Manufactured". Most items that have this date (e.g. Computers, TV's, etc.) usually provide just the month and year of manufacture. I experimented using "mmm-yyyy" in Perform's attributes section, but the compiler didn't like it!.. Is there an alternative without having to use a CHAR or DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH column?

EDIT: DBDATE=MDY4-

Comment: In most databases (which aren't providing subtypes for dates) the obvious way is to use the first day of the month. Or use built in to_date function to create a date from just a month and an year.

Comment: That's what I'm currently using, but would like to eliminate having to enter the day of the month and still be able to do TODAY(mm/yyyy) - MFGDATE(mm/yyyy) arithmetic. I'm wondering if using DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter a DATE in an ISQL screen, you must specify year and month and day in some order (and within broad limits, you get to control the order).  The DATE must be complete, though.  If you want only year and month, then you should use DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH; by definition, that does not accept a day value.

The only option left is to use the first of the month and have the form automatically provide the day value.  You could experiment with PICTURE and/or FORMAT clauses, but I'm not convinced they'll help.

Comment: You've confirmed my conclusions!.. picture will only work with field tags binded to character columns. I had previously experimented with DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH, but sformbld also complained, doco says YEAR must span to DAY?..

Comment: I've not looked at the docs, but if it says that DATETIME must include DAY and this is the actual behaviour, then it is documenting a bug.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong!.. It actually has to do with mixing the two classes of intervals, YEAR TO MONTH class with the DAY TO FRACTION class.

Comment: Phew!  I'm relieved to hear that.